# How can I add "-e" before each argument to a shell alias?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to simplify a bash command by making an alias that doesn't require adding -e to every term:

`alias mylog='tail -f /c/logs/elog.txt | grep --line-buffered -i auctions | grep --line-buffered --color -i'`

Then I call it with `mylog -e mask -e face -e belt` when I'd like it to be `mylog mask face belt`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think this only works with a function, not an `alias`.

Comment: Aliases are very simple -- they're nothing but prefix substitution. When in doubt, use a function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function instead of an alias lets you write code to manipulate the argument list:

```
mylog() {
  # write usage when called without arguments, because why not?
  (( "$#" )) || { echo "Usage: mylog arg1 [arg2 ...]" >&2; return 1; }

  # logic to calculate the argument list we want to pass to grep...
  local arg; local -a args=( )  # make these locals so we don't change outer scope
  for arg do             # this iterates over "$@" by default
    args+=( -e "$arg" )  # thus, adding -e "$arg" for each argument we were called with
  done

  # and then the actual pipeline we're here for
  tail -f /c/logs/elog.txt \
  | grep --line-buffered -i auctions \
  | grep --line-buffered --color -i "${args[@]}"
}
```